# Extracting String in Excel (SHADED/ACTIVE) Need column showing only SHADED

Tags: excel

I have a excel file with columns values Shaded/Active

I need to get sub string before / Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the column to text file (Notepad)

Paste list to excel and use text import wizard.  Select option Delimited and select / 
This will give you 2 columns :)

Answer (score 2):

`=LEFT(A1, SEARCH("/", A1) - 1)`

That's assuming that your cells actually contain the text: Shaded/Active and you want to extract the part before the /

You might need to clarify the question a bit if that isn't what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to add another column which serves as a flag to know if its shaded/active. I'm not sure if there;s way to know if a cell is shaded.